# Xelatex Calibri without serif math

Tags: xetex, sans-serif

I have to write a document in Calibri. Please find my minimal example thereafter.
The issue is when I include some math, the design looks "ugly".

**Is there a way to change the serif math font and number to some SANS-SERIF which looks close to Calibri?**

```
  \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{xltxtra}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
    \begin{document}


 \begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c }
\hline
            & Model 1 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $10.9983^{***}$ \\
            & $(0.0420)$      \\
a  & $0.0040^{**}$   \\
            & $(0.0016)$      \\
b         & $0.0053^{***}$  \\
            & $(0.0012)$      \\
c & $0.0052^{***}$  \\
            & $(0.0001)$      \\
\hline
R$^2$       & 0.9317          \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.9309          \\
Num. obs.   & 243             \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.01$, 
  \textsuperscript{**}$p<0.05$, 
  \textsuperscript{*}$p<0.1$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}

Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consectetueradipiscingelit. Utpuruselit,ves?bu-
lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam
arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula
augueeuneque.  

 \[
 \bar{x} = \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n}{n}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no Unicode math sans serif font, at the moment.

Comment: this won't help with the "real" math, but it shouldn't be necessary to use math coding for the numbers in the table.  for entries like `(0.0016)` try just removing the `$` signs.  since that column appears to be centered, those entries should align.  and for an entry like `0.0053^{***}`, try first removing the `$` signs, and then code the `***` as `\rlap{***}`.  i don't use calibri, but most text fonts have the `*` located in a "super" position, and the `\rlap{...}` will hide their width, again making the entry the same length as the others.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Hello yeah I was considering doing that. Is working well but as I use texreg package on R I get automatically the $ ... $ style. So I will see if someone has a better solution. If not I will manually make the changes and consider your solution which is finally working but takes just a bit more time... Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}% for the symbols
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{Calibri}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{Calibri-Italic}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c }
\hline
            & Model 1 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $10.9983^{***}$ \\
            & $(0.0420)$      \\
a  & $0.0040^{**}$   \\
            & $(0.0016)$      \\
b         & $0.0053^{***}$  \\
            & $(0.0012)$      \\
c & $0.0052^{***}$  \\
            & $(0.0001)$      \\
\hline
R$^2$       & 0.9317          \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.9309          \\
Num. obs.   & 243             \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.01$, 
  \textsuperscript{**}$p<0.05$, 
  \textsuperscript{*}$p<0.1$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}\label{table:coefficients}
\end{table}

Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consectetueradipiscingelit. Utpuruselit,ves?bu-
lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam
arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula
augueeuneque.  

 \[
 \bar{x} = \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n}{n}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I get an error it says "font-not-found" The font XITS Math cannot be found. I use miktex on win 7

Comment: Then use `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}`. However, you should be able to load XITS Math with MikTeX's package manager. You can also comment this line out, then the default math symbols are used.

Comment: Oh you right is working fine through the package admin. Thanks. Is working on my side

Answer (score 5):

There is no Unicode sans serif math font available. If your document uses math only marginally, then `mathspec` can help.

I use TeX Gyre Heros, because I don't have Calibri.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){TeX Gyre Heros}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{l c }
\hline
            & Model 1 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $10.9983^{***}$ \\
            & $(0.0420)$      \\
a  & $0.0040^{**}$   \\
            & $(0.0016)$      \\
b         & $0.0053^{***}$  \\
            & $(0.0012)$      \\
c & $0.0052^{***}$  \\
            & $(0.0001)$      \\
\hline
R$^2$       & $0.9317$          \\
Adj. R$^2$  & $0.9309$          \\
Num. obs.   & $243$             \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.01$, 
  \textsuperscript{**}$p<0.05$, 
  \textsuperscript{*}$p<0.1$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}

\end{table}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\bar{x} = \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n}{n}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note some changes to your document: don't load `xltxtra`; don't use `center` inside `table`; Never leave a blank line before a displayed equation.

[image]

Possibly a better way to typeset your table is by using `siunitx` and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){TeX Gyre Heros}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\newcommand\tnote[1]{${}^{#1}$}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2.4,
    table-space-text-post=\tnote{***},
   ]
}
\toprule
            & {Model 1} \\
\midrule
(Intercept) & 10.9983\tnote{***}      \\
\addlinespace[-.4ex]
            & {\footnotesize(0.0420)} \\
a           & 0.0040\tnote{**}        \\
\addlinespace[-.4ex]
            & {\footnotesize(0.0016)} \\
b           & 0.0053\tnote{***}       \\
\addlinespace[-.4ex]
            & {\footnotesize(0.0012)} \\
c           & 0.0052\tnote{***}       \\
\addlinespace[-.4ex]
            & {\footnotesize(0.0001)} \\
\midrule
R$^2$       & 0.9317             \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.9309             \\
Num. obs.   & {243}              \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.01$, 
  \textsuperscript{**}$p<0.05$, 
  \textsuperscript{*}$p<0.1$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}

\end{table}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\bar{x} = \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n}{n}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice, but why even bother with coding the numbers in the column as math?  they'd look much nicer with the decimal points aligned, and that doesn't need math coding.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Probably you're right. Maybe the table was just by way of example.